# how to create vouchers with cronjobs in hybris

Tags: cron, sap-commerce-cloud

i'm a newbie on hybris and i want to know how to create a cronjob that will
  - generate voucher starting from current and valid for a month. I'd like to mention the number of vouchers to generate

i'm really struggling .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is to create a new cronjob, to do so you need to :

- create a new item that extends Cronjob
- create an implementation of AbstractJobPerformable where the cronjob logic is
- Create a Spring bean for the new implementation
- Update your system
  [source](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/HelloWorldCronJob+Tutorial)

---

Second step is to create new vouchers use 'de.hybris.platform.voucher.VoucherService' to generate and save your voucher. You will need to create and save a new VoucherItem using ModelService, filling all data in it, use the voucher service generate code to get a new unique code.
[Source](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/Vouchers+-+Technical+Details)

---

Last step you will need to create a Trigger like this one using Impex:

```
INSERT_UPDATE Trigger;cronJob(code)[unique=true];second;minute;hour;day;month;year;relative;active;maxAcceptableDelay
;full-powertoolsIndex-cronJob;0;5;3;-1;-1;-1;false;false;-1
```

Comment: first thanks , but how to generate  voucher in the job and save them to the database

Comment: first thanks , but how to generate  voucher in the job and save them to the database , concretly i want to generate multiple voucher via a cronjob and save the to the database via a cronjob  i need more clarification please

Comment: You will need to create and save a new VoucherItem using ModelService, filling all data in it, use the voucher service generate code to get a new unique code.

Comment: why do we need to add an item  it still confusing me

Comment: An item means a record in your database, have a look a ModelService Interface.

Comment: Have you had a look at ModelService ?

Comment: yes it s all good now thank  i just wanted to have informations   if you , but i dont want to bother , thank you